# How to make a bootable disk from an image with Toast?

Tags: bootable-disk, dvd-burning

I read contradictory information, some say it’s possible, some say it’s not  and Apple’s Disk Utility is required.

I prefer to use Roxio Toast for its multi-purpose but I don’t want to waste blank disks.

So is it possible and if yes how to make a bootable disk (DVD or CD) from an image (dmg, iso, toast, cdr...)?

*I also heard that it must be burnt at the slowest speed.*

Comment: May I ask why you need to use Toast rather than Disk Utility?

Answer (score 1):

**Toast:**

1. "Do not mount the Disk Image first!"
2. Launch "Toast.app"
3. Click "Data" icon (upper left) and choose **ISO 9660**
4. Select "Copy" icon (upper left) and choose **Image File**
5. Click "Select" and "Choose a Disk Image File" from the dialog (do not drag and drop).
6. Click "Burn" et voilà.

[image: v2Toast.app]

---

**Disk Utility:**

1. Launch "Disk Utility.app"
2. Click "Burn" icon (upper left)
3. "Select image to burn" from the dialog (do not drag and drop).
4. Insert CD / DVD
5. Click "Burn" using the dialog.

[image: v2DiskUtility.app]

---

**Most effective Option:**

1. Launch "Terminal.app"
2. Use the following command(s). Replace "imagefile.dmg/.iso" with your **dir** and/or prefferd name.

   ```
   hdiutil convert imagefile.dmg -format UDTO -o imagefile.iso                
   hdiutil burn Imagename.iso
   ```

This method uses the exact pre-installed function of "Disk Utility.app" only without the GUI!

[image: v2Terminal.app]

Answer (score -1):

Go to Copy > From Image File, put an image (dmg, iso, toast, cdr...) into the Toast. Burn.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, it's simpler, cheaper and faster to use Disk Utility for bootable images.